# How to transform java regular expression to mysql regex

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I would like to push the regular expression evaluation down to a mysql database. Therefore I am looking for a way to transform a Java regular expression into a Mysql regular expression. Has anybody experience with such an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's support for regular expressions is rather limited. MySQL only has one operator that allows you to work with regular expressions. This is the REGEXP operator, which works just like the LIKE operator, except that instead of using the _ and % wildcards, it uses a POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE) - http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere .

You can see a comparison of regexps here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

and see if you have anything in java that is not supported in MySQL.